# Scan the keys in lwjgl

Tags: java, keyboard, lwjgl

I have this game where I use the standard WASD keys as input.

Though not all the keyboards have a QWERTY layout. For instance, when I use an AZERTY keyboard, the WASD is a bit hard to use with the left hand.

I would like that no matter his keyboard the layout, *by default* the player puts his left hand at the same place.

I've read that it is possible to do this using a mechanism called keyboard scanning that I should perform at the first launch of the game.

So how to perform such a keyboard scanning with LWJGL (preferably with version 3)? Is it possible at all?

Note: I've developed a user-mapping system. Here I'm really speaking about the best *default* mapping when the player starts the game for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to do any keyboard scanning if you use the `glfwGetKey` or `glfwSetKeyCallback` functions to receive input. Their [documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7e496507126f35ea72f01b2e6ef6d155) states

> The key functions deal with physical keys, with layout independent key
>   tokens named after their values in the standard US keyboard layout

If you need the actual character that was pressed, you can use [`glfwSetCharCallback`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga556239421c6a5a243c66fca28da9f742).

Comment: Well, thanks for the enlightenment, I sure never read this while investigating to migrate to LWJGL3! It should be easier now with this. I'll accept your answer, but test first naturally ;)